# R - stop(string) vs stop(cat(string1, ...))

Tags: r

In writing very simple validation code with R as per below, I would prefer the system error notification (i.e. Error in ....) to precede my string (e.g. n1 <= 0). It does this with
a simple string, but the order is the reverse, with a concatenated string. Many thanks for your help.

```
chk = function(n1,n2,n3){
  if (n1 <= 0){
    stop("n1 <=0")
  }
  if (n3 > n2){
    stop(cat("n3(=", n3 ,")>n2(=", n2, ")\n"))
  }
}

chk(0,1,2)
# prints --> Error in chk(0, 1, 2) : n1 <=0
chk(1,1,2)
# prints --> n3(= 2 )>n2(= 1 )
#            Error in chk(1, 1, 2) :
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cat()` function prints its `...` arguments to the console immediately unless you choose not to (with the `file` argument).  Its output is actually not a character string, but rather it is class `NULL`.  And since it is evaluated before `stop()`, it prints first.

You can fix this by replacing `cat()` with `paste()`

```
chk = function(n1,n2,n3){
    if (n1 <= 0){
        stop("n1 <=0")
    }
    if (n3 > n2){
        stop(paste("n3(=", n3 ,")>n2(=", n2, ")\n"))
    }
}

chk(0,1,2)
# Error in chk(0, 1, 2) : n1 <=0
chk(1,1,2)
# Error in chk(1, 1, 2) : n3(= 2 )>n2(= 1 )
```